# Cannot deploy cloud function because of missing service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, service-accounts

I'm trying to deploy a cloud function in a GCP project but I cannot do it because of this error:

```
"Default service account 'PROJECT_ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com' doesn't exist. Please recreate this account (for example by disabling and enabling the Cloud Functions API), or specify a different account. Please visit https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting for in-depth troubleshooting documentation."
```

When I look at the activity of my account, I see GCP is trying to create the service account but fails because of this error: `(HTTP 409): ALREADY_EXISTS`. However, I don't see the service account list with the other and while browsing the activity history, I can't find any indication that it may have been created one day. Since I took over this project from a contractor several months ago, I may be missing some historical context.

I managed to enable and use this API on another project. The only difference I see is that on the project where I managed to use Cloud Function the API was disabled and I had to enable it while on the project where I experience issues, the API was already enabled. No idea if it can have an impact.

I tried:

- To disable and re-enable the API after a time. No effect.
- To use `gcloud beta app repair` but the command fails with `ERROR: (gcloud.beta.app.repair) Apps instance [bankstore-preprod:repair] not found: Could not find Application "bankstore-preprod".` (it doesn't seem related to my problem).

Does anyone have an idea on how I can create this service account to use the Cloud Function API?

Comment: can you share your function definition  ( the runtime )

Comment: I can reproduce the issue with the default function for HTTP or Pub/Sub on NodeJS. Given the error, I think it's independent of runtime and function code.

Comment: is your PROJECT_ID  being replaced in your code by its value and  did you try to use another service account ?

Comment: `PROJECT_ID` is replaced in the error by our project id yes. I remove it before pasting the exception. From what I understand, this service account is supposed to be created automatically by GCP for Cloud Function management.
That's why it's in `@appspot.gserviceaccount.com` and not in `@PROJECT_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com`

Comment: did you delete your default  app engine service account?

Comment: _"did you delete your default app engine service account?"_ Not that I know off. Not willingly anyway. And as I said, I could find any trace of the creation or deletion in the activity log.